# How to parse JSON response and insert into Query

Tags: json, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I have the following JSON response and am really lost on how to insert that into a ColdFusion query using a loop.

The response is like this:

```
 {  
   "status":"OK",
   "data":{  
      "group_id":1522413460,
      "0":{  
         "id":"1522413460-1",
         "customid":"",
         "customid1":"",
         "customid2":"",
         "mobile":"0000000000",
         "status":"AWAITED-DLR"
      },
      "1":{  
         "id":"1522413460-2",
         "customid":null,
         "customid1":null,
         "customid2":null,
         "mobile":"0000000000",
         "status":"AWAITED-DLR"
      },
      "2":{  
         "id":"1522413460-3",
         "customid":null,
         "customid1":null,
         "customid2":null,
         "mobile":"0000000000",
         "status":"AWAITED-DLR"
      },
      "3":{  
         "id":"1522413460-4",
         "customid":null,
         "customid1":null,
         "customid2":null,
         "mobile":"",
         "status":"INV-NUMBER"
      }
   },
   "message":"Campaign of 4 numbers Submitted successfully."
}
```

I am using a `jsondecode` function from cflib to decode the response of JSON into a nested structure:

```
<cffunction name="jsonencode" access="remote" returntype="string" output="No" hint="Converts data from CF to JSON format">
    <cfargument name="data" type="any" required="Yes" />
    <cfargument name="queryFormat" type="string" required="No" default="query" /> <!-- query or array -->
    <cfargument name="queryKeyCase" type="string" required="No" default="lower" /> <!-- lower or upper -->
    <cfargument name="stringNumbers" type="boolean" required="No" default=false >
    <cfargument name="formatDates" type="boolean" required="No" default=false >
    <cfargument name="columnListFormat" type="string" required="No" default="string" > <!-- string or array -->
    <cfset var jsonString = "" />
    <cfset var tempVal = "" />
    <cfset var arKeys = "" />
    <cfset var colPos = 1 />
    <cfset var i = 1 />
    <cfset var column = ""/>
    <cfset var datakey = ""/>
    <cfset var recordcountkey = ""/>
    <cfset var columnlist = ""/>
    <cfset var columnlistkey = ""/>
    <cfset var dJSONString = "" />
    <cfset var escapeToVals = "\\,\"",\/,\b,\t,\n,\f,\r" />
    <cfset var escapeVals = "\,"",/,#Chr(8)#,#Chr(9)#,#Chr(10)#,#Chr(12)#,#Chr(13)#" />

    <cfset var _data = arguments.data />

    <!--- BOOLEAN --->
    <cfif IsBoolean(_data) AND NOT IsNumeric(_data) AND NOT ListFindNoCase("Yes,No", _data)>
        <cfreturn LCase(ToString(_data)) />

    <!--- NUMBER --->
    <cfelseif NOT stringNumbers AND IsNumeric(_data) AND NOT REFind("^0+[^\.]",_data)>
        <cfreturn ToString(_data) />

    <!--- DATE --->
    <cfelseif IsDate(_data) AND arguments.formatDates>
        <cfreturn '"#DateFormat(_data, "medium")# #TimeFormat(_data, "medium")#"' />

    <!--- STRING --->
    <cfelseif IsSimpleValue(_data)>
        <cfreturn '"' & ReplaceList(_data, escapeVals, escapeToVals) & '"' />

    <!--- ARRAY --->
    <cfelseif IsArray(_data)>
        <cfset dJSONString = createObject('java','java.lang.StringBuffer').init("") />
        <cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(_data)#" index="i">
            <cfset tempVal = jsonencode( _data[i], arguments.queryFormat, arguments.queryKeyCase, arguments.stringNumbers, arguments.formatDates, arguments.columnListFormat ) />
            <cfif dJSONString.toString() EQ "">
                <cfset dJSONString.append(tempVal) />
            <cfelse>
                <cfset dJSONString.append("," & tempVal) />
            </cfif>
        </cfloop>

        <cfreturn "[" & dJSONString.toString() & "]" />

    <!--- STRUCT --->
    <cfelseif IsStruct(_data)>
        <cfset dJSONString = createObject('java','java.lang.StringBuffer').init("") />
        <cfset arKeys = StructKeyArray(_data) />
        <cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(arKeys)#" index="i">
            <cfset tempVal = jsonencode( _data[ arKeys[i] ], arguments.queryFormat, arguments.queryKeyCase, arguments.stringNumbers, arguments.formatDates, arguments.columnListFormat ) />
            <cfif dJSONString.toString() EQ "">
                <cfset dJSONString.append('"' & arKeys[i] & '":' & tempVal) />
            <cfelse>
                <cfset dJSONString.append("," & '"' & arKeys[i] & '":' & tempVal) />
            </cfif>
        </cfloop>

        <cfreturn "{" & dJSONString.toString() & "}" />

    <!--- QUERY --->
    <cfelseif IsQuery(_data)>
        <cfset dJSONString = createObject('java','java.lang.StringBuffer').init("") />

        <!--- Add query meta data --->
        <cfif arguments.queryKeyCase EQ "lower">
            <cfset recordcountKey = "recordcount" />
            <cfset columnlistKey = "columnlist" />
            <cfset columnlist = LCase(_data.columnlist) />
            <cfset dataKey = "data" />
        <cfelse>
            <cfset recordcountKey = "RECORDCOUNT" />
            <cfset columnlistKey = "COLUMNLIST" />
            <cfset columnlist = _data.columnlist />
            <cfset dataKey = "data" />
        </cfif>

        <cfset dJSONString.append('"#recordcountKey#":' & _data.recordcount) />
        <cfif arguments.columnListFormat EQ "array">
            <cfset columnlist = "[" & ListQualify(columnlist, '"') & "]" />
            <cfset dJSONString.append(',"#columnlistKey#":' & columnlist) />
        <cfelse>
            <cfset dJSONString.append(',"#columnlistKey#":"' & columnlist & '"') />
        </cfif>
        <cfset dJSONString.append(',"#dataKey#":') />

        <!--- Make query a structure of arrays --->
        <cfif arguments.queryFormat EQ "query">
            <cfset dJSONString.append("{") />
            <cfset colPos = 1 />

            <cfloop list="#_data.columnlist#" delimiters="," index="column">
                <cfif colPos GT 1>
                    <cfset dJSONString.append(",") />
                </cfif>
                <cfif arguments.queryKeyCase EQ "lower">
                    <cfset column = LCase(column) />
                </cfif>
                <cfset dJSONString.append('"' & column & '":[') />

                <cfloop from="1" to="#_data.recordcount#" index="i">
                    <!--- Get cell value; recurse to get proper format depending on string/number/boolean data type --->
                    <cfset tempVal = jsonencode( _data[column][i], arguments.queryFormat, arguments.queryKeyCase, arguments.stringNumbers, arguments.formatDates, arguments.columnListFormat ) />

                    <cfif i GT 1>
                        <cfset dJSONString.append(",") />
                    </cfif>
                    <cfset dJSONString.append(tempVal) />
                </cfloop>

                <cfset dJSONString.append("]") />

                <cfset colPos = colPos + 1 />
            </cfloop>
            <cfset dJSONString.append("}") />
        <!--- Make query an array of structures --->
        <cfelse>
            <cfset dJSONString.append("[") />
            <cfloop query="_data">
                <cfif CurrentRow GT 1>
                    <cfset dJSONString.append(",") />
                </cfif>
                <cfset dJSONString.append("{") />
                <cfset colPos = 1 />
                <cfloop list="#columnlist#" delimiters="," index="column">
                    <cfset tempVal = jsonencode( _data[column][CurrentRow], arguments.queryFormat, arguments.queryKeyCase, arguments.stringNumbers, arguments.formatDates, arguments.columnListFormat ) />

                    <cfif colPos GT 1>
                        <cfset dJSONString.append(",") />
                    </cfif>

                    <cfif arguments.queryKeyCase EQ "lower">
                        <cfset column = LCase(column) />
                    </cfif>
                    <cfset dJSONString.append('"' & column & '":' & tempVal) />

                    <cfset colPos = colPos + 1 />
                </cfloop>
                <cfset dJSONString.append("}") />
            </cfloop>
            <cfset dJSONString.append("]") />
        </cfif>

        <!--- Wrap all query data into an object --->
        <cfreturn "{" & dJSONString.toString() & "}" />

    <!--- UNKNOWN OBJECT TYPE --->
    <cfelse>
        <cfreturn '"' & "unknown-obj" & '"' />
    </cfif>
</cffunction>
```

**Update #1:** with `DeserializeJSON`, I get the following screen shot. If I loop over results called `data`, how to nest the inside ones?

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: what version of ColdFusion are you using?  FYI there's a built-in `DeserializeJSON()` function

Comment: i am on coldfusion 11

Comment: remove the jsonencode code, and post what you've tried so far.

Comment: *insert that in coldfusion query* To clarify, do you mean you need to insert the results into a database table?

Comment: yes @leigh, more of the values which needs to be in DB are the structs which starts with 0,1 and so on

Comment: Does the response contain a field indicating the total number? Looks like it is contained in the "message", ie "Campaign of **4** numbers Submitted successfully." but... is there a separate total key? If not, take a look at the comments beneath Henry's answer.

Answer (score 1):

[JSON / CFML - Looping over an array of structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977052/json-cfml-looping-over-an-array-of-structs)

I asked something similar recently.

Looks like you have an array of structs. You can deserialize the JSON as others have described and loop through it as shown in my link.

## Edit just for clarity's sake

Here's the code that worked for me. I've edited out one step since the response you're getting doesn't seem to contain encoded characters.

```
<cfset requestBody = #(toString(getHttpRequestData().content)/>
<cfset ArrayOfStructs = deserializeJson(requestBody)>
<cfloop array="#ArrayOfStructs#" index="i">
<cfquery name="doodoodoo" datasource="CRM">
    INSERT INTO TimeAppTest
    (
        EmployeeID,
        lat,
        long,
        TimoStampo
        )
    VALUES
    (
        '#i.barcode#',
        '#i.lat#',
        '#i.long#',
        '#i.time#'

        )
</cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

The JSON was something like so, explaining the different variable names.

```
{"barcode":"CSS1035","scannerID":"3e81b04aa521a05e","time":"2015-08-11 08:30:27.232","lat":32.4001579,"long":-110.0403455},
{"barcode":"CSS1959","scannerID":"3e81b04aa521a05e","time":"2015-08-11 08:30:29.366","lat":32.4001579,"long":-110.0403455},
{"barcode":"CSS1649","scannerID":"3e81b04aa521a05e","time":"2015-08-11 08:30:31.642","lat":32.4001579,"long":-110.0403455}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. use `DeserializeJSON()` to convert to a struct `result`.
2. loop through the `result.data` with `<cfloop>`
3. use `<cfquery>` to construct a SQL INSERT statement, pass values by `<cfqueryparam>`

ColdFusion doc:
https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Home

Comment: `result.data` seems to contain different items. I see `group_id` and I see `0` and `1`. Looping is the solution but not trivial. Loop from 1 to 100 an test if an item exists. loop item and test if it is a number are possible solutions.

Comment: Strange the response does not indicate the total number of elements via some sort of key. If so, another possibility is to use structCount.  Assuming `data` always contains a `group_id` plus items 1 through N, you could calculate the number of items as `structCount(result.data)-1`. Then loop from 1 to `structCount(result.data)-1`. Though as @Bardware mentioned, be sure to test whether each key exists first.

Comment: this is where it gets confused, the returned `json` response is quite different and `DeserializeJSON` it did not return expected results, so an example of this sort how to actually write it, will help a lot

Comment: @Darek - That function is designed to do the opposite of what you need. It creates a json *string*. You already have a string. You need to decode it into CF objects so you can loop through them - which is what `DeserializeJSON` does. Using the comments above - can you show us what have you tried so far?