# How to connect the Finger print scanner on coldfusion based web application?

Tags: jar, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, fingerprint

I need to implement the Finger Print scanner on my web application. I am using the coldfusion 10 and 16. I know we can connect the some I/O device on coldfusion web app by using JAR files. But i searched on google regarding Finger Print scanner i couldn't find anything. Please let me know if anyone have the solution or idea or suggestion.  Thanking you

Comment: There might be several ways to do this... it depends on how the scanner itself transmits data.  I've worked with barcode scanners & similar tech that has a special API that will post to your server. Makes it real easy.  Can you share a sample of what the device outputs after you scan for prints?

Comment: My requirements is very straight forward thumb scanner scan the users thumb and then stored on data base final output will be integer or hexadecimal or binary data.

Comment: @TRose if you okay for you can you share your bar code scanner example code?

Comment: I doubt it's relevant, but I did ask a question about how to handle the data it outputs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977052/json-cfml-looping-over-an-array-of-structs

Comment: If you could provide an example of what happens after a scan, people might be able to help you.

Comment: I haven't worked on it but I found some resource like griaulebiometrics which will provide you fingerprint scanner API, please try it and also let me know if it is working fine. Here is the link:- http://www.griaulebiometrics.com/new/

Comment: @Justin Thanks. I will try that one and then I will let you know